# How to get submenu to appear below main menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

[Menu](http://jsfiddle.net/j1mmgtdr/)

NOTE: you may need to expand the Result Box

above is what i am trying to fix, the idea is that when you hover the Men and Women `<li>` elements a submenu appears below, this is why the hidden div is inside the `<li>` because then when you leave the link to go into the div it's not going to disappear. however my problem is that the other menu items are being pushed down.

Now before i did have it working, this is what i had

[Old Version](http://jsfiddle.net/sbaxe5m3/)

however i was requested to push the first 3 links to the left and the last link to the right. all i did was add floats which seem to be the cause. i have tried changing the display property, I've tried changing the position property however the only other result i get that the sub menu sets on the end and not under the menu.

I've about ran out of idea except for getting the x and y coordinates and using css to force the div to sit there however i don't think it'll work unless it's outside the `<li>`, What else can i do to get my submenu to work correctly while keeping the menu alignment as it is

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you wanted to achieve? I've added my CSS at the end, for the floating of the "Cart" entry, I added an ID (`cart`) to cart `<li>` element.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jtkzwup5/1/)

Here is a snippet.

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
  /* ie 6/7 */
}
/* Actual CSS */

#copyright {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#container {
  width: 930px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#navbar {
  border-top: 1px solid #686868;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #686868;
  /*padding: 5px;*/
}
/* Hero Footer List */

#herofooter ul li a {
  padding: 1em 2.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
#byline {
  background: #7D787D;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#herofooter ul li a {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-position:0.2em;*/
  background-position: left center;
}
.shipping a {
  /* width: 200px; */
}
#herocontainer {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #686868;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #686868;
}
.contactus a {
  background-image: url('/Pics/13901.png');
}
.store a {
  background-image: url('/Pics/13895.png');
}
.shipping a {
  background-image: url('/Pics/13905.png');
}
.returns a {
  background-image: url('/Pics/13909.png');
}
.store a {
  padding-left: 27px !important;
}
.shipping a {
  padding-left: 47px !important;
}
.secure a {
  background-image: url('/Pics/NortonVerisign-sml.png');
  padding-left: 75px !important;
  padding-top: .2em !important;
}
.loyaltyprogram a {
  background-image: url('/Pics/LoyaltyProgramIcon.png');
  padding-left: 23px !important;
  padding-top: .2em !important;
}
#herofooter ul li a:hover,
#footernav li a:hover {
  /* background-color: #efefef;*/
  color: #341414;
}
#herofooter ul li a,
#footernav a {
  color: #686868;
}
/* Footer extra buttons */

#footermenu {
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#footernav li {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#footernav li a {
  padding: 0.1em 2.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Font replacements */

#headernav {
  font-family: 'Oswald', 'Verdana';
  font-size: 20px;
}
#logotext {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Verdana;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 88px;
  color: #000;
}
#search {
  font-family: 'Oswald', Verdana;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
}
#herofooter {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#copyright {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#byline {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', 'verdana';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#herofooter ul li a {
  color #000 !important;
}
/* Hovers and animations */

#headernav a {
  transition: background-color .25s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color .25s ease;
}
#headernav a:hover {
  color: #CC3333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
/* Sale, logo colour */

#headernav a {
  color: #000000;
}
a#sale,
#logo {
  color: #CC0001;
}
#logo a img {
  border: 0;
}
/* Search */

#search {
  width: 185px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 25px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#stylesearch {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 190px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
#productsearch {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#searchbox {
  border: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #686868;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 140px;
  float: left;
}
#searchbox:focus,
#searchbox:hover {
  background: #FDFDFD;
  color: #000;
}
/* Header lists */

#navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar ul li {
  display: inline;
}
#navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  /*padding: 0 2em;*/
  /*float: left;*/
}
#mycart {
  float: right;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #7D787D;
  border-top: 1px solid #CC0001;
}
/* nav me */

.navme ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.navme ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#memberprogram p {
  /* margin: 0; */
}
#footermenu {
  text-align: left;
}
#footernav li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 145px;
}
.cartimage {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: -7px;
  border-style: none
}
.navbuttons {
  min-height: 30px;
}
.mega-menu {
  float: left;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  background: #aaaaaa;
}

/*--------Added CSS---------*/

.mega-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 500px;
}
#navbar ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#navbar ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#navbar ul ul li a {
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}
#navbar ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#navbar ul li#cart {
  float: right;
}
li.header {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showMenu(heading) {
    $(heading).find("div[class='mega-menu']").css({
      display: "block"
    })
  }

  function hideMenu(heading) {
    $(heading).find("div[class='mega-menu']").css({
      display: "none"
    })
  }
</script>
<div id="navbar" class="navbuttons">
  <ul id="headernav">
    <li><a href="/catalogdb/newarrivals.asp" id="new" style="float:left;">New Arrivals</a>
    </li>
    <li onmouseover="showMenu(this)" onmouseout="hideMenu(this)"><a href="/shopmens.asp" id="men" style="float:left;">Men</a>

      <div id="mens-cat" name="mens-cat" class="mega-menu" style="display: none; margin-top: -1px;">
        <div id="category" class="clearfix">
          <div id="categorycontent" class="clearfix">
            <ul class="clothing category">
              <li class="header">
                <h4>Clothing</h4>

              </li>
              <ul class="items">
                <li> <a href="/catalogdb/products.asp?category=163">Activewear</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/catalogdb/products.asp?category=143">Business Shirts</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/catalogdb/products.asp?category=11">Coats and Jackets</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li onmouseover="showMenu(this)" onmouseout="hideMenu(this)"><a href="/shopwomens.asp" id="women" style="float:left;">Women</a>

      <div id="womens-cat" name="womens-cat" class="mega-menu" style="display: none;">
        <div id="category" class="clearfix">
          <div id="categorycontent" class="clearfix">
            <ul class="clothing category">
              <li class="header">
                <h4>Clothing</h4>

              </li>
              <ul class="items">
                <li> <a href="/catalogdb/products.asp?category=27">Basic Tops</a>

                </li>
                <!-- <li><a href="/catalogdb/products.asp?category=177">Cathouse Suits</a></li>-->
                <li> <a href="/catalogdb/products.asp?category=185">Fashion Tops</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="/catalogdb/products.asp?category=36">Jackets</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="cart"><a href="/catalogdb/cart.asp?cmdView=-9" id="mycart">My Cart</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

see the jsfiddle code : http://jsfiddle.net/sbaxe5m3/2/

add this css:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
/* Actual CSS */

#copyright { text-align:center; margin:0px auto; font-size:10px; }

#container { 
    width: 930px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

#navbar {
    border-top: 1px solid #686868;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #686868;
    /*padding: 5px;*/
}

/* Hero Footer List */
#herofooter ul li a { 
    padding: 1em 2.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

#byline {
    background: #7D787D;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-bottom:12px;
    padding:5px;
}


#herofooter ul li a {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*background-position:0.2em;*/
    background-position: left center;
}



.shipping a {
/* width: 200px; */
}

#herocontainer {
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #686868;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #686868;
}

.contactus a {
background-image: url('/Pics/13901.png');
}

.store a {
background-image: url('/Pics/13895.png');
}

.shipping a {
background-image: url('/Pics/13905.png');
}

.returns a {
background-image: url('/Pics/13909.png');
}

.store a {
padding-left:27px !important;
}

.shipping a {
padding-left:47px !important;
}

.secure a {
background-image: url('/Pics/NortonVerisign-sml.png');
padding-left:75px !important;
padding-top:.2em !important;
}

.loyaltyprogram a {
background-image: url('/Pics/LoyaltyProgramIcon.png');
padding-left:23px !important;
padding-top:.2em !important;
}

#herofooter ul li a:hover, #footernav li a:hover {
/*  background-color: #efefef;*/
color: #341414;
}

#herofooter ul li a, #footernav a {
color: #686868;
}


/* Footer extra buttons */
#footermenu { width: 800px; text-align:center; margin: 0px auto;}
#footernav li { font-size:12px; }

#footernav li a { 
    padding: 0.1em 2.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Font replacements */
#headernav { 
    font-family: 'Oswald', 'Verdana';
    font-size: 20px;
}

#logotext  {
    font-family: 'Raleway', Verdana;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 88px;
    color:#000;
}

#search {
    font-family: 'Oswald', Verdana;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#000;
}

#herofooter {
    font-family: 'Raleway', Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#copyright {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#byline {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', 'verdana';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 24px;
}

#herofooter ul li a {
    color #000 !important;
}

/* Hovers and animations */
#headernav a {
    transition: background-color .25s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color .25s ease;
}

#headernav a:hover {
    color:#CC3333 ;
    color:#FFFFFF ;
}

/* Sale, logo colour */
#headernav a {
    color: #000000;
}

a#sale, #logo {
    color: #CC0001;
}

#logo a img {
    border: 0;
}

/* Search */
#search {
    width: 185px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:25px;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    margin-top:15px;
}


#stylesearch {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:190px;
    padding-top:2px;
    line-height:22px;
}

#productsearch {
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}

#searchbox {
    border:0;
    border-right:1px solid #686868;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    margin-top:1px;
    padding:5px;
    width:140px;
    float: left;
}

#searchbox:focus, #searchbox:hover {
    background: #FDFDFD;
    color:#000;
}

/* Header lists */
#navbar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#navbar ul li { display: inline; }

#navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 1.5em; /*padding: 0 2em;*/
    /*float: left;*/
}

#mycart {

}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #7D787D;
    border-top:1px solid #CC0001;
}

/* nav me */
.navme ul li { display: inline; }

.navme ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#memberprogram p 
{
/* margin: 0; */
}

#footermenu { text-align:left; }
#footernav li { display: inline-block; width: 145px; }

.cartimage
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -7px;
    border-style:none
}

.navbuttons
{
    min-height:30px;

}

#navbar ul li {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.mega-menu
{
    float: left;
    z-index:1000;
    position: inherit;
    text-align:left;
    background:#aaaaaa; left: 50%;
    margin-left: -327px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    width: 654px;
}
```